# Is it possible to spin up VM using Vagrant and provider as vSphere in free edition of ESXi?

Tags: vagrant, vmware, vsphere, esxi

We are using free edition of ESXi. Is it possible to spin up VM using Vagrant and provider as vSphere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible:

https://github.com/nsidc/vagrant-vsphere/issues/78

Answer (score 2):

Tools like that rely on the Web Services SDK to function and SDK support is only exposed on pay versions. Some of these tools even rely on features that are only included in vCenter which looks to be the case on that specific plugin. You can use the full version of vCenter and full version of ESX/i for 60 days in eval mode to test out these tools which can be useful in helping make a case to management/leadership to purchase the full versions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.  Here is the Vagrant Plugin that will talk directly to the ESXi host (without the need for vSphere).

https://github.com/josenk/vagrant-vmware-esxi